# bootstrap rectangle full width not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

New to using bootstrap, and am having trouble with a div rectangle that I would like to stretch full-width across the top of the page (much like the SO grey bar at the top). I have tried sizing to 100% and resetting margins, but nothing is working. I also tried taking the rectangle out of the container div, but then it disappears :(. I then tried making the rectangle a well instead, but that doesn't seem to want to let me set its height to 20px.

I've tried most of the rearranging-of-divs or using the !important as suggested on SO, but, for whatever reason, the divs aren't cooperating. I just want a blue bar to stretch across the top of the page, as per my bosses request :P

I'm a bit frustrated, and wonder if anyone can help me?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle span12"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <span class="span12">
        <img src="images/one-pager-blogcta-08.png" class="pull-right image">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the CSS

```
  body {
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
 }
 /* Set floating dom-heading margins to 0 */
 [class*="dom-heading"] {
   margin: 0;
 }
 .container .rectangle {
   background: #1f2f5f;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -o-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   border-radius: 0px;
   margin-left: 0px !important;
   border: none;
   height: 20px;
   width:100%;

 }
```

Site: intervalmed.com

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar rectangle">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--menu items-->
    </div>
</div> <!-- .navbar -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <span class="span12">
        <img src="images/one-pager-blogcta-08.png" class="pull-right image">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectangle {
   background: #1f2f5f;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -o-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   border-radius: 0px;
   margin-left: 0px !important;
   border: none;
   height: 20px;
   width:100%;

 }
```

Comment: This totally worked! I had tried moving the rectangle outside of the container, but things just weren't working. It was probably some mistake in the css (it's always something, right?)

Anyway thanks for posting so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the bar on top, you can just set a border to `<body>`

```
body {
    border-top: solid 20px #1f2f5f;
}
```

If you want an actual `<div>` with 100% of the document's width, then it should be outside the container, since the container is the one that wraps things with `max-width`

So just move your div outside container and set the height explicitly in your CSS (`<div>` elements will always fill it's parents width)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <!-- THE REST OF YOUR PAGE -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.rectangle {
    background: #1f2f5f;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I hadn't actually thought of setting a border to body.
That's really clever!

Comment: @bree I see you're new to StackOverflow, welcome! If you feel this answer helped you resolve your issue please consider voting it up and marking it as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark next to it. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info on accepting an answer.